# Encrypted windows partition with ubuntu / Grub configuration

Tags: grub2, encryption

guys i would like to encrypt my windows partition only , as i have dual boot  windows 7 ultimate and ubuntu 12.04. I would like to encrypt all my windows partition with truecrypt as i suppose you already now , but i was wondering how will it work ?

I suppose when i am gonna encrypt the whole partition of windows with true crypt , when i will boot linux grub will not find the partition ?! how can i do   for the grub to find my partition windows encrypted ? thanks guys

ps : basically more simple , i will encrypt my windows partition only , but grub will not detect anymore my windows partition?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in a simple way, yes.

> If your system partition or system drive is encrypted using TrueCrypt,
>   you need to enter your pre-boot authentication password in the
>   TrueCrypt Boot Loader screen after you turn on or restart your
>   computer. It may happen that you are forced by somebody to decrypt the
>   operating system or to reveal the pre-boot authentication password.
>   There are many situations where you cannot refuse to do so (for
>   example, due to extortion). TrueCrypt allows you to create a hidden
>   operating system whose existence should be impossible to prove
>   (provided that certain guidelines are followed — see below). Thus, you
>   will not have to decrypt or reveal the password for the hidden
>   operating system. [See here](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=hidden-operating-system) and [here](http://pzolee.blogs.balabit.com/2010/07/grub2-and-truecrypt-windows-linux-dual-boot-system/).

---

> In order to boot a system encrypted by TrueCrypt, an unencrypted copy
>   of the TrueCrypt Boot Loader has to be stored on the system drive or
>   on a TrueCrypt Rescue Disk. Hence, the mere presence of the TrueCrypt
>   Boot Loader can indicate that there is a system encrypted by TrueCrypt
>   on the computer.

Source: [redobackup.org](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=hidden-operating-system)

Comment: i do understand , but my initial question was , will grub find my encrypted partion ? as when i boot i have the grub menu , to select which os , as grub will not recognize my windows partition as it will be encrypted?

Comment: ok thanks for your answer , but that's the normal way of truecrypt working do i have to do any change to the linux grub? thanks